# Tags and category - ExpressionEngine

Tags: tags, expressionengine, categories, channel

I develop for the first time on EE and I don't really understand the categories.

I created categories with names and everything is linked.

When I'm selecting a category and update my post, on the blogpost page, every categories are displayed.

[image]
[image]

Here is the code:

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="blogs"}
   <li><a href="{path='blog/categories'}">{category_name}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

Second question :

Is there a way to have tags and categories ? with a dropdown menu or something like that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI: The EE focused SE site is now in public beta if you want to post future EE questions there: expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I'm selecting a category and update my post, on the blogpost
>   page, every categories are displayed.

The Channel Categories Tag shows all categories by default, regardless of whether any posts are categorized that way. To override this you just need to set the `show_empty` parameter to `no`

Try

```
{exp:channel:categories channel="blogs" show_empty="no"}
   <li><a href="{path='blog/categories'}">{category_name}</a></li>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

See the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/categories.html#show-empty)

---

**But**...Since from your comment it sounds like you want to just show categories assigned to a given entry, there is a different tag to use.

There is a variable pair available inside the Channel Entries tag for [categories](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories)

Inside your `exp:channel:entries` tag pair you will want to add something like

```
{categories}
    <a href="{path='your/template_path'}">{category_name}</a>
{/categories}
```

You might find some useful info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13104158/780434), too.

---

> Is there a way to have tags and categories ? with a dropdown menu or something like that ?

To have tags on your site you can use one of the tagging add-ons available for EE. I recommend [Tagger](http://www.devdemon.com/tagger/) or [Solspace Tag](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/tag/).

Comment: The show_empty="no" parameter display the categories from all the post, so If two post has differents categories, both of them are displaiyng the two categories on the screen.

Thanks you very much about Tagger ! It works like a charm !

Comment: Ah, so are you wanting to show just the categories assigned to a given post?

Comment: Exactly ! Maybe my question was not really clear, sorry about that ^^'

Comment: Ah, I will update my answer. You'll want to use a different tag, the [categories tag pair](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#categories), inside your channel entries loop.

Comment: Thanks you very very very veyr [...add number here...] much for your answers ! That really helps me !

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, the ExpressionEngine Stack Exchange site just went into public beta today, so if you have more EE questions definitely stop by the beta: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/